# What is a good approach to increase the depth of Nifti file format or Dicom file series?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, image-processing, bioinformatics, gan

I have a CT scan dataset of skull fracture consisting of multiple fractures and normal cases, the CT scans are in Dicom format. I want to do multi-class classification. But not every Dicom image series has the same depth, some series may have 250 slices, some have 30 slices. My dataset is really small, so I don't want to drop any 2d slice. And at the end, I will convert Dicom into Nifti for 3d CNN, so I need all the Dicom series to have the same depth. I want to artificially increase the depth of the Dicom series. I've read GAN is a popular way to increase medical image artificially. What are my other options?

Comment: This question is a bit cryptic because requires the readers to know what kinds of data formats are in Dicom and Nifti in order to answer it. Can you elaborate on what data you're storing (something to do with stacks of slices?) and what you want the NN to do in specific terms?

Comment: The data is the CT scan of the head. I want CNN to do multi-class classification.